# SQL update a column value depending the value of another column

Tags: sqlite, sql-update

I am using sqlite. I have a table like this

```
create table t (i integer, j integer)
insert into t values(100,210)
insert into t values(200,290)
insert into t values(300,100)
insert into t values(400,500)

I'd like to adjust the j column so that 
* j=j+10 if i=j+10 exist
* j=j-10 if i=j-10 exist

After the adjust the table would look like
select i,j from t
i   j
--- ---
100 200
200 300
300 100
400 500
```

Is there an UPDATE syntax that would allow this, or should I do a loop with an hosting language (C in my case)

I tried to read the UPDATE statement BNF, I guess CASE, should help, but so far I can't make it, my problem is about 'exist' how do I check inside the UPDATE, that a computed 'i' exist.

Thanx in advance, cheers. Phi

Answer (score 3):

Here is a single `UPDATE` statement which should work for your problem.  It's not my favorite answer because it updates *all* records, even those which have values of `j` which do match your criteria.  This means that some triggers might fire unnecessarily.

```
UPDATE t
SET j = CASE WHEN i = j + 100 + 10 THEN j + 10
             WHEN i = j + 100 - 10 THEN j - 10
             ELSE j
        END
```

If you don't mind two separate `UPDATE` statements, then you could try this:

```
UPDATE t
SET j = j + 10
WHERE i = j + 100 + 10

UPDATE t
SET j = j - 10
WHERE i = j + 100 - 10
```

Comment: Oops I took it for granted, this doesn't work as I asked. Since I am asking for a 'i' to exist in the table I guess there will be some join involved

Comment: @Phi I don't follow your reasoning, can you elaborate?  I think my answer should cover your problem well.

Comment: The UPDATE you gave don't touch anything in my example table because the WHERE i=j+10 refere to the current cursor (row), so when applying your UPDATE on my table I got no change at all because there is never a i=j+10 (j-10)

Comment: I think to make it we will need a recursive update along with a join

Comment: HO dunno if that matter but I am using SQLITE

Comment: Dunno why my added answers are going on top, so are not posted after your replies. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved it, not sure it is the best way to do it but here is what I do.

```
Before
select * from t
i   j
--- ---
100 210
200 290
300 100
400 500

First pass, fix the j with j+10 were we can find i=j+10
update t set j=j+10 where rowid in
     (select t.rowid from t,t as u where t.j+10=u.i)

select * from t
i   j
--- ---
100 210
200 300 <== only this got corectly updated
300 100
400 500

Second pass fix the j with j-10 were we can find i=j-10
update t set j=j-10 where rowid in
      (select t.rowid from t,t as u where t.j-10=u.i)"
select * from t
i   j
--- ---
100 200 <== only this one corectly updated
200 300
300 100
400 500
```

I guess there are more elegant ways to do this.

Cheers,
Phi